# Get direct children Elements at any depth

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a Comments system whose listing has, in its essence, the following format:

```css
body {
  font-size: 1.15rem;
}

.comment {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}

  .comment .message {
    margin: 0 1rem;
  }

  .comment .replies {
    margin-left: 15px;
  }

.icon {
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
           align-self: center;

  display: -webkit-inline-box;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;

   -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

  .icon.dots {
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 1.5rem;
    width: 1.5rem;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row comment" data-author="author1">
  <div class="col w-175 message">
     @author1 - Lorem ipsum dolor
  </div>
  <div class="col tools">
    
    <div class="dropdown dropstart">
      
      <svg class="icon dots" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" role="menu">
        <use xlink:href="#dots" />
      </svg>
      
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="follow">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="ms-2">Follow</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="d-none follow">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)">
            <span class="ms-2">Unfollow</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="row replies">
    <div class="col">
      
      <div class="row comment" data-author="author2">
        <div class="col w-175 message">
          @author2 - Reply #1
        </div>
        <div class="col tools">
          
          <div class="dropdown dropstart">
      
            <svg class="icon dots" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" role="menu">
              <use xlink:href="#dots" />
            </svg>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="follow">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                  <span class="ms-2">Follow</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="d-none follow">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                  <span class="ms-2">Unfollow</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="row replies">
          <div class="col">

            <div class="row comment" data-author="author1">
              <div class="col w-175 message">
                @author1 - Reply #2
              </div>
              <div class="col tools">
                
                <div class="dropdown dropstart">
      
                  <svg class="icon dots" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" role="menu">
                    <use xlink:href="#dots" />
                  </svg>

                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="follow">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <span class="ms-2">Follow</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="d-none follow">
                      <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <span class="ms-2">Unfollow</span>
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                
              </div>
              <div class="row replies">
                <div class="col">


                  <div class="row comment" data-author="author2">
                    <div class="col w-175 message">
                      @author2 - Reply #3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col tools">
                      
                      <div class="dropdown dropstart">
      
                        <svg class="icon dots" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" role="menu">
                          <use xlink:href="#dots" />
                        </svg>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li class="follow">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                              <span class="ms-2">Follow</span>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="d-none follow">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                              <span class="ms-2">Unfollow</span>
                            </a>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="row replies">
                      <div class="col">...</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-none">
  <svg id="dots" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M12 16.5c.83 0 1.5.67 1.5 1.5s-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5.67-1.5 1.5-1.5zM10.5 12c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67-1.5 1.5zm0-6c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5s1.5-.67 1.5-1.5-.67-1.5-1.5-1.5-1.5.67-1.5 1.5z"/>
  </svg>
</div>
    </svg>
```

As you can see, comments have an identifier data-attribute with authors' usernames and each Comment has a toolbox of sorts, which I've simplified to one action here.

In this simple example, when the User clicks the **Follow* entry, it should flip all of Bootstrap's `d-none` class on `.follow` and `.unfollow` on all toolboxes belonging to that author, so it's possible to Follow/Unfollow without reloading the Page.

Initially, I tried:

```
const username = 'author1'; // This actually comes from the data-attribute read when clicking the link

const $toolbox = $( sprintf( '[data-author="%s"] .tools', username ) );
```

> sprintf() is a 3rd-party component because I honestly don't really like Template Literals

An honest attempt, but when I wrote it I forgot that this would also bring all matching Elements from child selectors. For example, if the variable `username` above had the value `author1`, entries on `author2` toolbox would also be changed.

Then I've narrowed the selector:

```
const username = 'author1'; // This actually comes from the data-attribute read when clicking the link

const $comment = $( sprintf( '[data-author="%s"] .tools', username ) );
const $toolbox = $comment.children().find( '.tools' );
```

While it solved the previous problem, it created a new one: now entries nested within `.replies`, even those that DID match the data-attribute, would not change.

Then I tried something silly:

```
const username = 'author1'; // This actually comes from the data-attribute read when clicking the link

const $comments = $( sprintf( '[data-author="%s"]', username ) );

$comments.each( ( _offset, comment ) => {

  const $this = $( comment );

  const $toolbox = $this.children().find( '.tools' );

  $toolbox.find( 'li.follow' )
          .addClass( 'd-none' )
          .siblings( 'li.unfollow' )
          .removeClass( 'd-none' );
});
```

And it worked perfectly, but I'm executing the same instructions over and over and over again N times as the data-attribute matches.

How could I accomplish that more efficiently?

[EDIT]

In this very minimalist scenario, the Child Combinator Selector (`>`) does the trick, however, in the real layout made with Bootstrap Grid, it doesn't. For reference, this is an example of the whole CSS Path:

```
div#comment_1212130616.comment.gx-0 div.row.gx-3.profile div.col.align-self-center div.row div.col-2.d-flex.flex-row.justify-content-end.tools
```

Comment: You're missing a `)` in the assignment to `$toolbox`.

Comment: Use `x > y` to mean `y` is a direct child of `x`

Comment: Typo fixed, thank you. Regarding the question, in this isolated case it worked, however, in the real scenario, with the whole layout markup made with Bootstrap Grid, as expected, it didn't because the toolbox `.tools` is not a direct child of `.comment`. I'll update the question with the entire CSS Path to it.

Comment: I know, but it was the best I could do to describe. I'm sorry. :(

Comment: instead of .children .find why not just `.children('.tools')`?

Comment: Hard to tell without the real example, including a nested comment, but perhaps:  `$("[data-author='author1'] :not([data-author]) .tools")`